# Avoid call function with a parameter call many times

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
function myalert(x)
{
  alert("hey + " x)
}
```

i am calling a afunction with different parameters

```
myalert("A");
myalert("B");
myalert("C");
myalert("A");
myalert("B");
myalert("C");
myalert("A");
myalert("B");
myalert("C");
```

can I avoid that ugly repetition?

update=**But what if 2 parameters? How will I make the "LIST" you are talking about?**
Example:

```
function myalert(x,y)
{
  alert(y + "hey + " x )
}

myalert("A", "X");
myalert("B", "X");
```

How can i make a list of this?

Comment: Pass the values in a list or array and loop?

Comment: are you looking for a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean by two parameters? Example please

Comment: @thefourtheye Example given;

Answer (score 1):

Loop it. You can get function arguments using `arguments` and their count `arguments.length`.

```
function myalert()
{
  var count = arguments.length;
  for(var i = 0; count > i; i++) {
     alert("hey + " + arguments[i]);
  }
}

myalert('a', 'b', 'c'); // alerts a, alerts b, alerts c
```

Comment: +1 Although i posted an answer, but your answer is better :) Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Put all parameters in an array, then use a loop.

```
var params = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

for (var i = 0, l = parmas.length; i < l; i++) {
    myalert(params[i]);
}
```

or:

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].forEach(function(e) {
    myalert(e);
});
```

Comment: You also need to repeat this 3 times.

Comment: @Barmar Just for an example. I think the op just use the dummy code not for real.

Answer (score 0):

```
myalert(['A', 'B', 'C']);

function myalert(dataArray)
{
  dataArray.forEach(function(e) {
    alert("hey " + x);
  });
}
```